# Array initialization with error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memset

Tags: c, visual-c++

Compiler: VC2013

I have an array as below:

```
typedef char CHAR8;
CHAR8 buffer[HEX_DUMP_BUFFER_LENGTH];
```

With below code, I get an `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _memset`

```
for (i = 0; i < HEX_DUMP_BUFFER_LENGTH; i++){
    buffer[i] = 'a';
}
```

But with manual assignment to an array element, there's no link error.

```
buffer[0] = 'a';
```

Why?

Comment: `#define CHAR8 char`, i.e. turn around, drop the `; `. Otherwise [mcve] please.

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry, it's a typo when I post this thread. In the actual code it's `typedef`. Corrected.

Comment: MCVE, pretty please.

Comment: Your MCVE is too M and not enough C and V.

Comment: The compiler seems to optimize this loop into a single `memset(buffer, 'a', HEX_DUMP_BUFFER_LENGTH)`, which is a good thing to do. Something must be wrong with your environment or linking, as `memset()` is part of the standard library that should always get linked.

Comment: See [`memset()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fdeehz6.aspx) -- the result is exactly the same as your loop, but it performs better.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I would not count too much on it. In the case of an `std::vector<int>` I measured time of `for` loop vs. `memcpy()` and got the opposite result (i.e. `for` was faster) to my ful surprise... (It was in VS2013, too.)

Comment: @Scheff whether `memset()` is faster or not depends on the implementation and target platform, but it is *potentially faster* and the compiler can assume this (or, better yet, knows the target platform well enough to decide). `memset()` can never be *substantially* slower.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f99tchzc.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant good hint, but does it explain the linker error?

Comment: @Yunnosch I *assume* the snippets really *do* show all relevant code and the problem is somewhere along the lines of compiler/linker flags...

Comment: It is just my superstition, that making too small an MCVE causes the error to be in what was left out.

Comment: I experimented a little bit with the presented code surrounded with a main function. To see what's compiled I enabled ASM output for Release. (In Debug, it looks straight forward, of course.) Probably the output is dependend of `HEX_DUMP_BUFFER_LENGTH`. Thus, I tried 16, 32, and 1024. All I got was a partly unrolled loop (in the 2 former cases not anymore a loop) of `mov`s - no call of `_memset()`. I considered also Hans' hint (`/Oi`) but it didn't change anything...

Comment: @Scheff I don't have MSVC here, but testing with `gcc -O3`, I *do* get a `call _memset` in the assembly when the buffer is really huge (tested with `8192 * 1024` aka 8MiB).

Comment: @FelixPalmen The OP stated (in the 1st text line) to use VC2013 (which I have at hand). I tried 8192 * 1024 also and got a new effect: The output is now `rep stosb` (with some preparing `mov`s before). Hmm. This could be an inlined `_memset()` or just another optimization of the back-end. I guess your former suggestion about compile/linker flags was fully sufficient. Without further input, there will be no progress in this issue...

Answer (score -2):

For some performance reason, the compiler will optimize your code.
You can disassemble your binary file to find out if the compiler has done it.
And you can adjust the compile flag, optimize level, or link the lib for the symbol of _memset.